# Unpack List in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
listA = ["one", "two"]
listB = ["three"]
listC = ["four", "five", "six"]
listAll = listA + listB + listC
dictAll = {'all':listAll, 'A':listA, 'B':listB, 'C':listC,}


arg = ['foo', 'A', 'bar', 'B']
result = [dictAll[a] for a in arg if dictAll.has_key (a)]
```

I get the following result [['one', 'two'], ['three']]
but what I want is ['one', 'two', 'three']

how do I unpack those lists in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
>>> [x for a in arg if dictAll.has_key(a) for x in dictAll[a]]
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

The order has always been confusing to me, but essentially it nests the same way it would if it were a loop.  e.g. the left most iterable is the outermost loop and the right most iterable is the innermost loop.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why the OP' code did not get the required result

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(dictAll.get(a, []) for a in arg))
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Also don't use `dict.has_key` it is deprecated(and removed in Python 3), you can simply check for a key using `key in dict`.